# Spring + ActiveMQ: Mismatch between concurrent workers

Tags: spring-mvc, activemq-classic, message-queue

My environment is Spring 3.0.5, ActiveMQ 5.8.
In `servlet.xml` I am specifying 10 concurrent consumers. However, ActiveMQ web admin console shows 'Number of Consumers' = 20.

```
<bean id="singleConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="msgListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="singleConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="emailRequestQ" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="emailRequestMessageListener" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
</bean>
```

Trying to figure out if my configuration is missing something?[image]

Comment: your config is perfectly fine. Do you have multiple instances running? Do you have multiple instances of your listener? Try to connect to ActiveMQ with jconsole. It has some info about who is connected to what queue etc.

Comment: What is the behaviour if you replace the spring singleconnectionFactory with a org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory ?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a couple things causing this to happen. For instance, if you are actually instantiating the bean with a constructor in the code instead @Autowiring, it would create two instances.

Also, the number of current consumers may not be accurate if you had a larger number of consumers and then decreased them as they may just go idle.

I would suggest switching to a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. This will allow you to play with the `maxConcurrentConsumers` property and access some additional data from the container with:

```
@Autowired
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container;
...
container.getActiveConsumerCount();
container.getConcurrentConsumers();
```